# Avalonia DataGrid Enter handling

Tags: datagrid, avalonia

I'm using `Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid`. By default, when the grid has focus and Enter is pressed, it automatically handles the event and moves the selection to the next item. How can I prevent this default behavior? I'd like to have a custom Enter KeyDown handler instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the `KeyDown` event cannot be used here, because specifically for `Enter` it's swallowed by the DataGrid before custom code can handle it.

Instead, [Key bindings](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Input/KeyBinding/) work. You can bind the key to a command like this:

```
<DataGrid ...>
  <DataGrid.KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" />
  </DataGrid.KeyBindings>
  ...
</DataGrid>
```

This also stops the grid from moving to next item when Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1- Give your datagrid a name (use x:name)

2- put this in your constructor :

```
yourDataGridName.KeyDown += yourDataGridName_KeyDown;
```

3- add this handler :

```
protected void yourDataGridName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
         //Put your custom code here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work, though - the Avalonia.DataGrid component is "clever" in that is handles the Enter automatically and stops it from propagating before user code can catch it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/10130

I use AddHandler for DataGrid. As the developer advised.

```
dataGrid.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown, RoutingStrategies.Tunnel);

private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{  
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).